# Checked Password Locked Account on Linux Without Root Privilege

Tags: linux, root, system-administration

my situation is that I sshed into one of the Linux computers in a general computer lab of a University, and my goal to get the information of which user actually logged in that computer and is using the computer. Since how the system is setup is that if somebody logs in and he or she could lock their account so that the computer could be logged in by someone else. He or she can unlock by entering the password again later. Because of this feature, if I do command such as "ps -aef | grep login", it gives me a list of users who have logged in, like this:

***user_name  22113  1  0 May28 ? /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login***

I know I can use commands such as "w", "who", "finger" and etc to get a list of users who have logged in like this:

***user_name :0 :0  25May16 ?xdm?   1:40m  5.56s gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]***

But I can't find a command that can check if logged-in user is currently in a "lock" state or using the computer right now. Google told me to use "passwd" or "usermod" to check the state of a user. But both of them requires root privilege, which I can't get from the IT department of the university.

So I am wondering if anyone knows a command that can check the state of each logged in user (whether they are in a "lock" state, or he or she is using the computer) not requiring the root privilege. My goal is to write a script that check if anyone has logged into a computer and is currently using the computer. Right now I can only get a list of logged-in users. But I can't tell who is actually using the computer. The Linux distribution is CentOS.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: I'd say that depends on the type of session the users run (I assume you are referring to _graphical_ sessions in your question). For KDE and GNOME at least you might be able to find out scanning the `dbus` system.

Comment: TBH you're already at the mercy of Linux leaking a lot of information between non-privileged processes. On Windows, the equivalent of `ps - aef` _is_ secure between non-privileged accounts.